# How to downgrade Oracle Java 7 to Java 6?

Tags: java, downgrade, oracle

I recently changed my Wubi install into a full install, which runs a lot smoother than Wubi. I had to re-install all my stuff, because I did it the lazy-man's way, and after reinstalling Java, I decided to use Oracle's build, as it's known to be more stable, and there's not a single Java program that breaks under Oracle's.

But, now I find that certain programs, namely 3D ones, are having some big glitches, and I know for a fact these glitches are caused by Java 7 being not-so-Java 6-ish, as the same programs work fine under my Windows boot, which has Java 6 on it.

There is some information that may make it seem like I want to run OpenJDK, or something, but that is not the case. I just want to know how to downgrade from Oracle Java 7, down to Oracle Java 6.

Thank you.

EDIT: To install, I used the following method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 3):

You can uninstall  it with [ppa-purge](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ppa-purge):

1) Install ppa-purge: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

2) Purge your java ppa: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java`

3) Then you can [download Java-6 from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre-6u32-downloads-1594646.html),

4) Open a terminal and make the downloaded file executable: `chmod +x ~/path/to/downloaded/file`

5) Run the installer: `~/path/to/downloaded/file`

If you are feeling lazy, and agree with [Oracle License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html), just paste this at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java ; cd ~/ ; p=$(uname -p) &&  if [ "$p" = "x86_64" ] ; then wget -c http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u32-b05/jre-6u32-linux-x64.bin ; else wget -c http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u32-b05/jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin ; fi ; chmod +x ~/jre-6u32-linux* ; sudo ~/jre-6u32-linux*
```

Comment: It didn't work to uninstall Java. I found a number of remanants of Java 7 remaining after doing what you'd suggested, to the point where Java 7 is still running, and Java 6 is nowhere to be found in my system, save for the home folder.

Comment: That is weird. Can you try to manually uninstall the remaining packages before the step 3?

Comment: If oracle 7 is still there after trying desgua's answer try 'sudo update-alternatives --config java'